# Console application help! C#

Tags: c#, console

I'd like to make a c# console application that: Opens a command line, writes line "Type in a command" and if the command was not found it writes "Not found". I come from LUA and I basically want to translate this to c#.

```
function something(cmd) 
    if cmd == "asd" then 
        print ("ASD") 
    else if cmd == "asd2" 
        then print ("You wrote ASD2") 
        end 
    end 
end
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your title and question

Comment: Google and the MSDN docs will provide the information you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type in a command.");
        string command = Console.ReadLine();
        YourMethod(command);
        Console.ReadKey(); //prevents the console closing before you can read the output
    }

    static void YourMethod(string cmd)
    {
        if(cmd == "asd")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ASD");
        }
        else if(cmd == "asd2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote ASD2");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this is what you specified, however please see Camilo's comment about proper question formatting in addition to Toggy's link.